# Kubernetes autoscale based on internal application parameter

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Given a Kubernetes cluster that runs a certain application in a pod, is there any way to **expose an internal parameter of the application** (e.g., socket buffer, concurrent requests in the application, number of items in a certain application queue …,  ) and then asks the `Kubernetes horizontal/vertical pod autoscaler` to scale up or down based on the value of such internal parameter application?

Comment: One way is to advertise these metrics from service and act based on that service's output. Hoping you have thought about this, do you have any issues around doing it?

Answer (score 2):

surely HPA supports [custom metrics](https://towardsdatascience.com/kubernetes-hpa-with-custom-metrics-from-prometheus-9ffc201991e). You can push your custom metrics to prometheus and configure HPA to scale up on your metrics.

There's a more beautiful article on how to use HPA custom metrics with prometheus to scale pod. You can refer the below link for more details.

https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/custom-metrics-api.md

Comment: Thanks, how about scaling on several cutom metric simulatensously and speicfy cutom formula for the desired number of instances based on the previous number of instances, and the simultaenous custom metrics where the formula could be linear or non linear.

Comment: You will need a custom solution then. 1. Write a separate deployment that read metrics and controls scale. 2. Use built-in role for `system:controller:horizontal-pod-autoscaler` (https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/). Use smth like prom-http-client or just requests to query https://pypi.org/project/prometheus-http-client/ 3. Calculate using formula. 4. Scale the deployment via https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python